# Is there a way to select a value from a column that has commas?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if there was a way to select from a column that has comma separated values.

For example, the column has this data: ('16', '20', '27', '2', '3')

Is it possible to do something like this:

-- get value 16 from table:-

```
select from table where value = '16'
```

or maybe use in?

```
select from table where value in '16'
```

Comment: **Don't** store comma separated values, it is a [**bad idea**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/7998591)

Answer (score 1):

If the column `value` contains data **with single quotes** like this:

```
'16', '20', '27', '2', '3'
```

then you can use the operator `like`:

```
select * from table where value like '%''16''%'
```

If there are **no single quotes** and the data is like:

```
16, 20, 27, 2, 3
```

then:

```
select * from table 
where ',' || replace(value, ' ', '') || ',' like '%,16,%'
```

If there are not any spaces between the comma separated values then you can don't need `replace()`:

```
select * from table where ',' || value || ',' like '%,16,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below if the value column has single quotes [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8a63/1)

```
        select * from tt where REGEXP_LIKE(value1,'(''16'',)[^,]+');
```

if it doesn't have single quotes use the below [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8a63/2)

```
   select * from tt where REGEXP_LIKE(value1,'(16,)[^,]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the database schema violates the [first normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)